# Does this translate to "son in law"?

Tags: translation-check, translation-explanation

I have a translation for the following Latin text "Rex, ne speraveris generum mortali stirpe creatum, ..." that is as follows "King, do not hope for a son in law born as a mortal.". Is this translation correct and does the text refer to a "son in law"?

Comment: What is the context of this sentence? It might be that the translator was not working sentence by sentence, but took some structural freedom. It looks like an adapted [quote from Apuleius](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=generum+mortali+stirpe+creatum).

Comment: As Joonas said, some context would be helpful. But *generum* does indeed mean son-in-law (from gener, -ī).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lewis & Short does indeed give "son-in-law" as the translation of *gener*, with a few closely-related terms:

> I. Lit.: “cum soceris generi non lavantur,” Cic. Off. 1, 35, 129; cf.: “mei viri gener,” Plaut. Cist. 4, 2, 87: “generum nostrum ire cum adfini suo,” id. Trin. 3, 1, 21: “et gener et affines placent,” Ter. Heaut. 5, 1, 63; cf. id. ib. 4, 8, 25; id. And. 3, 3, 39; id. Hec. 4, 1, 22: “C. Fannium et Quintum Scaevolam, generos Laelii,” Cic. Rep. 1, 12; id. Lael. 1, 3; 8, 26; id. Att. 4, 2, 4; Caes. B. G. 5, 56, 3; Quint. 6 praef. § 13; Hor. C. 2, 4, 13; Ov. F. 3, 202; Vulg. 1 Reg. 18, 18 et saep.
>
> —Also, a daughter's bridegroom, Hor. Epod. 6, 13; Verg. A. 2, 344; cf.: “generi et nurus appellatione sponsus quoque et sponsa continetur,” Dig. 38, 10, 6.—
>
> II. Transf.
>
> A. The husband of a granddaughter or greatgranddaughter, for progener, qui conlegam et generum adsciverat Sejanum, Tac. A. 5, 6; 6, 8; cf.: “generi appellatione et neptis et proneptis tam ex filio quam ex filia editarum, ceterarumque maritos contineri manifestum est,” Dig. 50, 16, 136.—
>
> B. A sister's husband, brother-in-law, Just. 18, 4; Nep. Paus. 1.—
>
> C. Comically, of a daughter's paramour: “Villius in Fausta Sullae gener, etc.,” Hor. S. 1, 2, 64.

So it looks like your translation is exactly right!